# Stripe Account Disappeared from Dashboard

Tags: wordpress, api

I had an account recently processing payments in USD for a site and a few days ago it vanished without a trace from the dashboard within Stripe. It is a subscription based site which makes use of Foxycart / Foxyshop wordpress. Within foxycart there is an area in which I have placed keys.

The only thing that has changed last week is that I set up a new wordpress installation on same server which also charged USD in Test Mode only.

This does not make use of FOxycart and I am using woocommerce and a woocomerce plguin for subscriptions + stripe.

The Stripe account used for the second site is a separate stripe account.

I have contacted Stripe 4 times in last 4 days with no answer whatsoever. The original account is still processing payments for subscriptions that have previously been set.

I was thinking I could always set up a new account and update keys within Foxycart but am not sure if this will affect past subscriptions in any way. I would like to retain records as well fdrom previous transactions. Help appreciated as my client is very upset.